# ocamlfind, where to find/how to build?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I know next to nothing about ocaml, but I want to install [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) (on cygwin), which has a dependency to the binary `ocamlfind`.

However, installing either ocaml-3.11.0-win-mgw.exe or ocaml-3.11.0-win-msvc.exe
from http://caml.inria.fr/download.en.html, there are no such binary. In fact not a single  file in the installed directory contains any reference to the string "ocamlfind".

And downloading the source code (ocaml-3.12.1), grep only finds the following references:

```
./Changes:- PR#5165: ocamlbuild does not pass '-thread' option to ocamlfind
./Changes:- PR#5217: ocamlfind plugin should add '-linkpkg' for toplevel
./ocamlbuild/command.ml:        else None (* Sh"ocamlfind ocamlc" for example will not be digested. *)
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:  | Cannot_run_ocamlfind
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:  | Cannot_run_ocamlfind ->
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:let ocamlfind = "ocamlfind"
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:        run_and_parse Lexers.ocamlfind_query
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:          "%s query -l -predicates byte %s" ocamlfind name
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:          "%s query -a-format -predicates native %s" ocamlfind name
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:        run_and_parse Lexers.blank_sep_strings "%s query -r -p-format %s" ocamlfind name
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:          (* TODO: Improve to differenciate whether ocamlfind cannot be
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:          error Cannot_run_ocamlfind
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:  run_and_parse Lexers.blank_sep_strings "%s list | cut -d' ' -f1" ocamlfind
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:make another ocamlfind query such as:
./ocamlbuild/findlib.ml:  ocamlfind query -p-format -r package1 package2 ... *)
./ocamlbuild/lexers.mli:val ocamlfind_query : Lexing.lexbuf ->
./ocamlbuild/lexers.mll:and ocamlfind_query = parse
./ocamlbuild/lexers.mll:  | _ { raise (Error "Bad ocamlfind query") }
./ocamlbuild/manual/manual.tex:\texttt{ocamlfind}).  Here is the list of relevant options:
./ocamlbuild/ocaml_specific.ml:  if !Options.use_ocamlfind then begin
./ocamlbuild/ocaml_specific.ml:      (* Note: if there is no -pkg option, ocamlfind won't be called *)
./ocamlbuild/ocaml_specific.ml:if not !Options.use_ocamlfind then begin
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:let use_ocamlfind = ref false
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:    "ocamlyacc"; "menhir"; "ocamllex"; "ocamlmklib"; "ocamlmktop"; "ocamlfind"]
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:let ocamlfind x = S[V"OCAMLFIND"; x]
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:   "-use-ocamlfind", Set use_ocamlfind, " Use ocamlfind to call ocaml compilers";
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:  if !use_ocamlfind then begin
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:    ocamlc := ocamlfind & A"ocamlc";
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:    ocamlopt := ocamlfind & A"ocamlopt";
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:    ocamldep := ocamlfind & A"ocamldep";
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:    ocamldoc := ocamlfind & A"ocamldoc";
./ocamlbuild/options.ml:    ocamlmktop := ocamlfind & A"ocamlmktop";
./ocamlbuild/signatures.mli:  val use_ocamlfind : bool ref
./ocamlbuild/signatures.mli:    | Cannot_run_ocamlfind
./ocamlbuild/signatures.mli:      (** Transitive closure, as returned by [ocamlfind query -r]. *)
```

and none of this is any references to install of such a binary. So I am sort of lost on how to proceed. Go back to older releases of ocaml?

BTW, the native ocaml cygwin packages did also not contain any ocamlfind binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is google down today? http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/findlib.html

There is no precompiled binary, but on cygwin it compiles fine out of the box.

Comment: Out of the box is a bit relative, it has a dependency to ncurses-devel which I did not have. But yes, when that was solved, it compiled fine.

Comment: ncurses? There is some tui wizard, but it is optional afair. I definitely compiled it on fresh cygwin and mingw installs without any additional steps.